# How to stop the corrosion?

Tags: frames

I have a silly question maybe.. How to protect the frame of my bike from corrosion? The bike is not new.  Are there any accessories? 
Thanks

Comment: What is the frame material?

Comment: Sacrificial anode - the way the navy does.  But then of course you have to keep the bike submerged in water.

Comment: Store it inside out of the weather.  Wash off any road/sea salt immediately you stop riding

Comment: Vote to close.  Cannot answer without knowing the material.   If you have existing corrosion please post a picture(s).

Comment: OP mentioned in comment that it was a steel frame in one of the answers.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming your bike is made out of steel (since aluminium and carbon fiber don't corrode in the way you're most probably worried about):

- Get "[helicopter tape](http://www.racerstape.com/heli.html)" to protect any areas of the bike that might get dinged (the top tube and down tube from parking the bike against parking meters, etc.). Or if you're cheap or worried about theft, use ugly duct tape / pipe insulation / electrical tape/etc. I use [retroreflective](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/30595/i-got-glow-in-the-dark-tape-where-do-i-place-it/30603#30603) tape which serves two purposes -- keeps me lit up at night and protects me against scratches.
- Make sure your rear right chainstay has a [chain protector](http://www.chainreactioncycles.com/us/en/lizard-skins-chain-stay-protector/rp-prod4760) on it.
- Get some touch-up paint from either your bike dealer or from an auto-parts shop and make sure to quickly touch up any dings and scratches. This is where corrosion will start.
- Get some [Boeshield](http://boeshield.com) or frame corrosion protection spray ([JP Weigle Frame Saver](http://homebicyclemechanic.com/how-to-make-a-steel-frame-last-forever/) is another brand) and spray the inside of your frame. The seat tube and top-tube can be sprayed if you take the seat off. The down-tube often has a drain hole but can be hard. Read the directions of what you're using to make sure it's safe for your bottom bracket or headset.
- Spray boeshield or another waxy protection film on all exposed bolts.
- Try to never leave your bike out in the rain and if you do, wipe it down as soon as possible.
- Keep your bike clean. Dirt and salt attract water and aid rusting.
- Occasionally make sure all of your frame drain holes are clear.
- Don't worry about a little rust, wear it with pride.

Many of the answers here are also applicable: [How do I make my frame water tight?](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/28665/how-do-i-make-my-frame-water-tight?rq=1)

Comment: I've sprayed tar-based anti-corrosion fluid (the kind used in cars) into an older steel frame. The top tube and the seat tube are of an easy access with the seatpost removed. The downtube and sometimes the chainstays can be reached when you remove the bottom bracket. The fork and the seatstays often have small drainholes. So far the frame shows no rust after 20+ years.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer and comments.
Yes, the bake frame is made of steel. I will start with the Boeshield spray to slow down the corrosion.
Any paint will be good? http://www.ebay.com/itm/Specialized-Bicycles-Matte-black-touch-up-paint-Bike-flat-/221715443817 I found a spray can in the garage. Here https://www.mrosupply.com/paint-painting-supplies/spray-paint/1386188_k07902000_krylon/ Can I spray it on the places with the scratches and rusty spots?

Comment: I would only use Boeshield or Frame Saver inside the frames - as they're designed for that. For the outside, any paint is OK. Just be sure that the overspray from your spray paint doesn't get on any moving parts or cables. You can make a spray guard with a cardboard box to prevent overspray.

Answer (score 3):

Frame rust is the least of your problems. It's the rust on your moving parts that you should worry about. I've never actually seen a frame on a working bike fail due to rust - the chain and the bearings will seize long before it gets to that stage. So, in order of priority:

1. Park the bike inside, or at least under a roof. Even if you ride every day, your bike spends more time parked than it does riding.
2. Clean and lube all the moving parts, especially the chain. Proper lubrication is a lengthy subject, and I won't attempt to cover it here, just keep in mind that the choice of lube depends on the application, and that WD-40 is *never* the right choice.
3. If your bike is exposed to salt (from the sea, or from road de-icing) then you should wash it regularly.
4. If there are scratches on the frame that penetrate all the way to bare steel, then cover them up. Any waterproof paint should work for touch-ups. Some people use nail polish. If the metal has already started to rust, remove *all* the rust before painting. Stickers or electric tape will also work for covering scrapes and preventing new ones.

Comment: I did once see a bike that was rusted through completely at the downtube shifter bosses.  It was, incredibly, still being used, even though the downtube was broken completely in two at that point.  But I agree that in general frame rust is not a significant concern, and if proper measures are used to prevent rust elsewhere then frame rust is at most a cosmetic concern.